# javascript / ajax / php herf link not working right

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am facing a problem that I just can't figure out for the life of me. I have a main welcome page where all my content loads via a javascript / ajax script
that I found at Dynamic Drive. However the problem that I am facing is that any form I have coded in PHP or HTML will not return the input fields to the PHP script. I have spent days trying to find a simple solution to this with no luck so at this point I'm just looking to this great coding community for ideas or help.  This is the link to ajax / javascript in use to do the loading:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm

Also any other link works great and loads fast. I'm just having issues with adding forms and I would like to have user added images to their profiles and that sort of thing on my site. Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to read this and offer help, Clayton.

This is the javascript / ajax script that loads everything inside of my container div on my `welcome.php` page. Below that is the form code that I have set up on my `settings.php` page.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Dynamic Ajax Content- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* Please keep this notice intact
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

var bustcachevar=1//bust potential caching of external pages after initial request? (1=yes, 0=no)
var loadedobjects=""
var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname
var bustcacheparameter=""

function ajaxpage(url, containerid) {
    var page_request = false
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
        page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
        try {
            page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } 
        catch (e){
            try{
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            }
            catch (e){}
        }
    } 
    else
        return false

    page_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        loadpage(page_request, containerid)
    }

    if (bustcachevar) //if bust caching of external page
        bustcacheparameter=(url.indexOf("?")!=-1)? "&"+new Date().getTime() : "?"+new Date().getTime()
        page_request.open('GET', url+bustcacheparameter, true)
        page_request.send(null)
    }

    function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
        if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
        document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText
    }

    function loadobjs(){
        if (!document.getElementById)
            return
        for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        var file=arguments[i]
        var fileref=""
        if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file)==-1){ //Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
            if (file.indexOf(".js")!=-1){ //If object is a js file
                fileref=document.createElement('script')
                fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
                fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
            }
            else if (file.indexOf(".css")!=-1){ //If object is a css file
                fileref=document.createElement("link")
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
                fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
            }
        }
        if (fileref!=""){
            document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
            loadedobjects+=file+" " //Remember this object as being already added to page
        }
    }
}



</script>
```

```html
<form name="settings" id="settings" action="javascript:ajaxpage('../addons/settings.php?action=update', 'container');" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="image" id="image" placeholder="picture url"/>
    <input type="text" name="mname" id="mname"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Some of your code would help, the forms, the PHP that processes the forms, etc.

Comment: and then I have a php action in that same file as the form that looks like this <?php

if($_GET['action'] == 'update')
{
echo"{$_GET['image']}<br>{$_POST['mname']}";
}
?> just to see if I can get anything to work ... I kinda think that the javascript isn't passing the inputs to the php